# how to use python to find out the minimum radius needed so that all the powdered sugar should fit in a cylindrical box

Tags: python

So lets say i have a packet of powdered sugar that has almost the same shape as a straight prism with a length of 8 cm,
width 6 cm and height 16 cm.
how can i create a program with a function that takes the length, width and height as
input parameters and then use a while loop to estimate the minimum radius so that
all the powdered sugar should fit in a cylindrical box with a height of 10 cm.

I tried this:

```
import math as mt
import numpy as np

volum = 8*6*16 #8cm 6cm 16cm
"""
jeg kommer til å generere tilfeldige tall for bredde og lengde
til jeg får det riktige svaret jeg leter etter.

"""

radius = np.random.randint(0, 10)
height = 10
svar = height * mt.pi * radius ** 2 
while(svar != volum):
    radius = np.random.randint(0, 10)
    height = 10
    svar = height * mt.pi * radius ** 2 
    if round(svar) == volum:
         print("minste radius for at all melisen skal få plass i en sylinderformet boks med høyde 10 cm er: ", radius)
```

Comment: are you expecting that pi*integer will result in an integer?

Comment: i don't really know what to say, at this point i think my program is useless to solving the problem

Comment: you know how to compute the exact radius right? the random method is your assignment?

Answer (score 0):

Your current solution is to check random integer radii between 0 and 10, compute the cylinder volume, and see if it matches the box. It doesn't work because all the possible cylinders you test are these:

```
>>> height = 10
>>> [round(height * math.pi * radius**2) for radius in range(11)]
[0, 31, 126, 283, 503, 785, 1131, 1539, 2011, 2545, 3142]
```

while your box has a volume of 768, so you will never find an exact match.

I would say the closest way to your original idea is to loop through all those values until you find one that's bigger than your desired volume, then exit the loop:

```
height = 10
for radius in range(11):
    svar = height * mt.pi * radius ** 2 
    if round(svar) >= volum:
        print("minste radius for at all melisen skal få plass i en sylinderformet boks med høyde 10 cm er: ", radius)
        break
```

(As I'm sure you know, the exact answer to your problem is `sqrt(volume / (pi * height))` which is around 4.944 so your loop should stop at 5.)